# Connecting Ubuntu 18.04 to Google WiFi

Tags: 18.04, wireless, google

When I try to connect a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 to my home Google WiFi, I am repeatedly presented with the pop-up dialog "Authentication required by wireless network".

Googling this problem yields several instances of this question with no solution presented :(

I have tried saving the password under the Security tab in Network Manager, and also followed some directions where I used wpa_supplicant where it just freezes after displaying "Successfully initiated wpa_supplicant"

What is the next step?